# Specify receiver on lambda literal without type inference

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I want a lambda expression which has the type of `Foo.()->Unit`

Obviously I can specify it by relying on type inference, such that the lambda captures the recipient type: `val myLambda: Foo.()->Unit = { ... }`

My intuition was that I could do something like: `val myLambda = Foo.{ ... }`

But that doesn't appear to work.  It seems weird that I can't express a lambda value of a particular type without depending on type inference from the lhs.

Is there a syntax I'm just not aware of?

Comment: There is no syntax like `Foo.{...}` youhave to write type explicitly when writing lambdas with receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax that does precisely what you're looking for. As you've already laid it out, you can create a lambda that has `Foo` as its receiver either by creating it as you're passing it into a function that takes such a lambda:

```
fun useFooExtension(fooExtension: Foo.() -> Unit) {
    fooExtension(Foo())
}

useFooExtension {
    println(this is Foo)
}
```

Or by specifying the type of the variable explicitly, like so:

```
var foo1: Foo.() -> Unit = { println(this is Foo) }
```

However, you *can* declare a lambda that takes a `Foo` as its first parameter, with this explicit lambda syntax (the variable type is only here for explanation purposes, it's otherwise redundant and is inferred):

```
var foo2: (Foo) -> Unit = { foo: Foo -> println(foo is Foo) }
```

And these two types of lambdas are actually cross-assignable, because the extension on `Foo` really just takes that `Foo` as its first parameter under the hood as well. So you can do all of these things:

```
foo1 = foo2
foo2 = foo1

useFooExtension(foo1)
useFooExtension(foo2)
```

There is one difference between the two types: if you want to call them with a `Foo` instance, you can only call `foo1` as an extension, but you can call both of them as if they took a `Foo` as their first parameter. So these are all valid calls:

```
Foo().foo1()

foo1(Foo())
foo2(Foo())
```